# use function for each item in clause mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to use unhex function for each item in the string seperated by comma. In this string this binary id as string sent by front end.

```
select * from table where id in
('5534B753765411E6B3FA0021004B111C,1668309A6E6F11E6B405F819928F1AD1,4FE75C954EEB11E6BB970F782D79D6C8')
```

I want to use this like

```
select * from table where id in (unhex('5534B753765411E6B3FA0021004B111C'),unhex('1668309A6E6F11E6B405F819928F1AD1'),unhex('4FE75C954EEB11E6BB970F782D79D6C8'))
```

Comment: You can't use unhex in a `where` clause. Check the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex

Answer (score 1):

IN's also support SELECT statements, so you could try using that functionality like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table WHERE id IN
(SELECT UNHEX('5534B753765411E6B3FA0021004B111C')
UNION ALL
UNHEX('1668309A6E6F11E6B405F819928F1AD1')
UNION ALL
UNHEX('4FE75C954EEB11E6BB970F782D79D6C8'));
```

Comment: code is not working. actually I have to call this inside stored procedure and all above string values will be inside parameter.

Comment: It's no fault of pachonk that this example is not working, it's yours for not disclosing full information.

Comment: If this isn't working, please provide the proper information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where 
     FIND_IN_SET(id,'5534B753765411E6B3FA0021004B111C,
     1668309A6E6F11E6B405F819928F1AD1,4FE75C954EEB11E6BB970F782D79D6C8');
```